# Распаковка программы

Tags: ассемблер

Доброго времени суток! Выучил Assembler, стал вникать в пинтест, вчасности дизассемблирование. Взлом неупакованной программы тупо заменой пары байт это легко и понятно, НО! Как распаковать программу упакованную, не надо кидать примеры с такими простыми упаковщиками как UPX. :)

Comment: [Фига крекер](http://34555555)

Comment: @Alex78191 ????  ЧТОООООО

Comment: cracker, cracker

Comment: @Alex78191 Может поможете? Какой-нибудь материал?!)

Comment: слишком сложное и к сообществу не относится

Comment: @Alex78191 Как бы не так)

Comment: @Razor я бы сказал, что вопрос слишком широкий. Для снятия простых упаковщиков есть специальные инструменты. Для снятия сложных навесных защит гуглим конкретный тип защиты, если повезёт, то находим статью на несколько страниц по теме. Универсального алгоритма распаковки, который сработает во всех случаях, просто нет.

Comment: Забавно звучит, "выучил ассемблер". Вы правда выучили наборы инструкций x86, x86-64, fpu, mmx, sse, sse2 и т.д.?

Comment: @insolor x86, x64, mmx знаю

Comment: @Razor, ну этого мало чтобы говорить, что выучили:) Вообще, "учить" не нужно, нужно знать и уметь применять (или знать как "расшифровывается"). На практике идеально знать (любой язык) невозможно, да и не нужно.

Comment: @insolor Я про то, что видя неупакованную программу, у меня нет проблем с ее взломом, однако с распаковкой...

Comment: @Razor, опять же - это слишком широкая тема для вопроса на stackoverflow. Берете конкретную упакованную программу, пробуете понять чем она запакована (есть инструменты для этого), гуглите как этот конкретный упаковщик/протектор можно снять, если что-то не понятно задаете вопрос на Stackoverflow (или скорее на Reverse Engineering).

Comment: Это вы проги взламываете для торрент трекеров?